# css layout bottom leave blank space

Tags: html, css

My current page is leaving small blank area near footer. Not sure what causing the problem. Below is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/test_style.css">

<body>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="sidebar">
            this is a test
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

test_style.css:

```
body {
    margin: 0; }

#header {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ccccff; }
#header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em; }
#main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: top;
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #009999; }

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background: #999900;
            }

#footer {
    clear: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #666600;
    padding: 20px; }

#navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333; }
#navigation ul {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0; }
#navigation ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline; }

#navigation li a {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    color: #ffff99;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left:  1px solid #fff;
    padding: 5px; }

#navigation li a:hover {background: #383}
```

Comment: and there is no `float: top` (#main)

Comment: @Justinas You do realize it's just a productive for you to create one and edit the question as it is to ask the OP to do the same?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/68aa3/) is a JSFiddle with fixed CSS-code. It seems you don't have any ID or Class defines to your CSS.

Comment: @TiesonT. He has 1 reputation, he must learn how to make it, or else you will be editing his questions forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1) Change `float: top;` to `float: left;` for `#main`:

```
#main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #009999;
}
```

2) Add `clear: both;` to `#main`:

```
#main {
    clear: both;
}
```

The reason it isn't working as you have it, is that you've floated the element within `#main` (the `#sidebar`) to the left, which sort of messes up the structure of the `#main` div. That means that `#sidebar` is placed just below the element above (`#navigation`) while `#main` is placed at the very top of the page (behind `#navigation`, so the top is not visible) causing it to not come down as far as the `#sidebar` div.

Just to exemplify: Another way to do it would be to add the height of `#navigation` (which in my browser is 28px) to the padding of `#main`, so:

```
#main {
    padding-bottom: 28px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explaination :)

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left; to your #main

```
#main {
float:left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: top;
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #009999; }
```

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/cNZ46/1/

Comment: You left the top float there and even so, this is a bad idea, even that it fixes the whitespace before footer. It's because the sidebar is inside the main content, but it's of course how he wants to build his site, still not recommended for this structure.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `float: left;` for design purposes. In regards to SEO it would be worse actually to separate the two divs if `#main` doesn't contain any content.

Answer (score 0):

[Here (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/68aa3/1/) is a fixed code with both HTML and CSS changes.

Notice that I moved **#sidebar** out from the **#main** so that they're apart from each other. Also I changed footer's **clear** to **both** which fixed the whitespace above it.

```
<div id="main">
   <p>Main content here!</p>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
   <p>Sidebar here!</p>
</div>
```

I've set up a **min-height** to both, sidebar and main area, just to show you it works.